# Integrate a sum in R

Tags: r, sum, integration

I am trying to compute the MISE of an estimator and for that i need to do the integral of :

```
(fp(x) - f(x))^2 where f(x) is exp(-x) and fp(x) is : sum_{i}^n { (1/n)*((K((x - X[i])/h))/h) }
```

The problem here is that X is a matrix, and i don't know how integrate this sum. 
I've tried this :

```
  Kgauss <- function(u) dnorm(u)  #Gaussian kernel  
  func = function(x, n, h, X){ ((1/n) * sum(Kgauss((x-X[0:n])/h)/h) - exp(-x))^2 } # h, n are constants
  vfunc = Vectorize(func)
  integrate(vfunc, n = 3, K = Kgauss, h = 0.25, X = rexp(3), lower = 0,  Inf)
```

But sadly it didn't work out. The big problem here is `fp(x)`, it consists of the sum of multiple functions .
I hope you can help me with this one, I've been struggling for a while now.

Basically i want to make : integral((K(X1) + ... + K(Xn) - exp(-x))²)

Comment: Your problem statement does not define `X` as an object. In this case I think the immediate problem is that `Vectorize` (aka `mapply`) is attempting to index the Kguass function. It's not clear why you don't just build that function into `func`.

Comment: I just added X into the arguments (and edited here too) but it still gives me the exact same error. What do you mean by building that function into func ? If you are talking about Kgauss this is because i used Kgauss at multiple places in my code so i just put it as a parameter but i guess i could have used it inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the n, h, and K outside the `func` and then have `x` as the only parameter:

```
n = 3;  h = 0.25; X = rexp(3)
func = function(x){ ((1/n) * sum(dnorm((x-X[0:n])/h)/h) - exp(-x))^2 } 
vfunc = function(x) { sapply(x, func)}
integrate(vfunc,  lower = 0, Inf)
# 0.2070893 with absolute error < 1.7e-05
```

(I'm not sure that you even need to vectorize `func`. It's built with vectorized functions already.)